# how many solutions of $ 3^a-7^b-1=0 $ equations

Tags: number-theory

I want to know how many solutions solutions of  $ 3^a-7^b-1=0 $ exists . I have got $ x-y=1 $ eqn when I have assumed that $3^a=x$ and $ 7^b=y $ .I cant proceed from here . Here $ a $ and $ b $ are real numbers

Comment: None. Looking $\pmod 3$, the LHS is $-1$, while the RHS is $1$. Unless, of course, $a=0$, but even that one can't give any solutions, since $3\not\mid 7^b$.

Comment: Alternatively, this is a consequence of [Catalan's conjecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture) (Mihăilescu's theorem)

Comment: Of course, that's assuming integer solutions.

Comment: I am puzzled: this is tagged number theory, while it says $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: No natural number solutions, since $3^a-7^b-1$ is usually odd. You hardly need Catalan, @EricNaslund

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinitely many real solutions - given any real $b$, let $a=\log_3 \left(7^b+1\right)$.

There are no natural number solutions since $3^a-7^b-1$ is always odd. You can prove likewise that there are no integer solutions, I believe.

Comment: There are no integer solutions: If $3^a-7^b-1=0$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, then multiply by $3^{|a|}7^{|b|}$ to get another triple of odd numbers that sum to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for integer solutions, then there are no integer solutions. This is because
$$7^b \equiv 1 \pmod3 \implies -7^b \equiv -1 \pmod3 \implies -7^b \equiv 2 \pmod3$$
Hence, we get that $3^a-7^b \equiv 2 \pmod3 \implies 3^a-7^b -1\equiv 1 \pmod3$